# How do I stop Adobe Reader from updating?

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-reader

After Adobe Reader auto-updated itself to version 15.023.20053 I was no longer able to print PDFs.

I restored back to the previously installed version (15.020.20042) and was able to print fine, but Adobe Reader keeps trying to update.

How do I stop Adobe Reader from updating (and breaking) itself?

Comment: Please let me know if my answer worked for you. Thanks!

Comment: If you **never** update, you are exposed to [vulnerabilities.](https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/acrobat/apsb17-11.html) . You should just prevent *automatic* updates.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by changing a key in registry:

[image]

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Adobe ARM\Legacy\Reader\{Product Code}
```

You need to change the key `Mode` :

```
0: Do not download or install updates automatically.
1: Do not download or install updates automatically.
2: Automatically download updates but let the user choose when to install them.
3: Automatically download and install updates.
4: Notify the user downloads are available but do not download them.
```

Set it to `0` to de-activate the automatic updates.

Comment: as much as my solution is your solution, working in regedit directly is never suggested for users that may not be comfortable being there. Pressing the delete key by accident on something that they accidentally selected could break their whole system.

Answer (score 1):

Answer as of 2021 and version 11.

**Adobe updates: Cannot be more convoluted**

For years this software publisher with some [poorly designed](https://www.cnet.com/news/jobs-why-apple-banned-flash-from-the-iphone/) but intrusive products has acted with methods from the past. Modern competitors and open source software are especially welcome to make Adobe Reader a thing of the past, like Flash Player. That said for the moment Acrobat Reader is still to be dealt with as much as we can, us poor users. Be aware there are two options:

- Prevent updates the hard way.
- Prevent **automatic** updates and select another mode of update.

When disabling updates (first option), the "check for updates" entry in the application menu is also removed. While preventing automatic updates is legitimate, e,g. to close an open door for security concerns, preventing all updates forever is not a good idea anyway. It is used by large organizations which disable access to an update server and push new installers from their own infrastructure.

This is [how Adobe sees the update process](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/etk_deprecated/tools/QuickKeys/WIN_UpdaterQuickKeyAll.pdf):

[image]

Configuration can done using a [customization wizard](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/automatic-updates---acrobat-reader.html) which acts on the product installers directly, but it can also be done manually after the installation, by updating the keys in the registry.

**Option 1: Customization wizard**

The customization is intended to companies with volume licensing, and work prior to the installation, by configuring the installer. There are [tons of pages in the help](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/Wizard/index.html) provided, but none directly related to update of Adobe Reader. So let's say goodbye to this first option.

**Option 2: Manually disable any update (not recommended) `bUpdater`.**

[Source](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/PrefRef/Windows/Updater-Win.html).

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\FeatureLockdown\bUpdater`
or
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\11.0\FeatureLockdown\bUpdater`

- Description by Adobe: Disables the Updater and removes associated user interface items.
- A DWord32. Set the value to 0 to disable the Updater.

Setting this key to 0 disable any update and remove any possibility to manually update using the menu. Note this setting is linked to the version of the reader, and will be ineffective after the next release, you'll need to change the key. Adobe's method.

**Option 3: Select another mode of update than automatic: `iCheck` and `iCheckReader`**

[Source](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/PrefRef/Windows/Updater-Win.html).

> `iCheck` configures both Acrobat and Reader until 10.1. After 10.1,
> use `iCheckReader` for Reader.

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Adobe ARM\1.0\ARM\iCheck`
or
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Adobe ARM\1.0\ARM\iCheckReader`

Current version is 11 and `iCheckReader` should be used for it. This key must be given a DWord value depending on the desired type of update, typically you may give a value of 4, corresponding to being informed of updates prior to deciding to download them:

> 0: Do not download or install updates automatically.
> 1: Do not download or install updates automatically.
> 2: Automatically download updates but let the user choose when to install them.
> 3: Automatically download and install updates.
> 4: (11.0 and later) Notify the user downloads are available but do not download them.

Answer (score -1):

> Lets Create a Script that blocks all Updates for Adobe. (Specific
>   solution at the end)

**1. Open Notepad.exe**

**2. Paste this code into it:**

```
echo off
REM *** initial taskkill to avoid conflicts
taskkill /im AcroRd32.exe
taskkill /im AcroRd64.exe
taskkill /im Acrobat.exe
Print Stopping Adobe Reader Updates
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\7.0\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\8.0\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\9.0\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\10.0\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\11.0\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\12.0\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\13.0\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\14.0\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\15.0\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
Print Stopping Adobe Acrobat Updates
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\7.0\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\8.0\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\9.0\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\10.0\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\11.0\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\12.0\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\13.0\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\14.0\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\15.0\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\DC\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
Print Stopping Adobe Air Updates
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\AIR" /v UpdateDisabled /d 0x00000001 /t REG_DWORD /f
Print Stopping Adobe Flash Updates 32/64-bit
C:
cd\Windows\system32\Macromed\Flash
if exist mms.cfg goto :next
echo "SilentAutoUpdateEnable=0" > mms.cfg
echo "AutoUpdateDisable=1" >> mms.cfg
:DoneFlash32
cd\windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\flash\
if exist mms.cfg goto :next
echo "SilentAutoUpdateEnable=0" > mms.cfg
echo "AutoUpdateDisable=1" >> mms.cfg
:DoneFlash64
cls
pause
```

**3. save as `UpdateBlockeradobe.bat`**

**4. Right click the saved file and run as administrator.**

**5. That's it :) No More Updates!**

> **If you want a specific solution to your problem and nothing else then**
>   **save this code instead of the one above:**

```
echo off
REM *** initial taskkill to avoid conflicts
taskkill /im AcroRd32.exe
taskkill /im AcroRd64.exe
taskkill /im Acrobat.exe
Print Stopping Adobe Reader Updates
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\15.0\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
Print Stopping Adobe Acrobat Updates
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\15.0\FeatureLockdown" /v "bUpdater" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
cls
pause
```

**Edit #1: updated response to question version(s).**